# how to Download binary (.txt file) data from sql via web service

Tags: c#, sql, service, web

i have successfully uploaded and downloaded a txt file via binary to the local sql with this code here.

```
byte[] FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(txtUpload.Text);

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCFTest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT into upload (Path,Data,Username,Email,Price,Description)values(@path,@data,@username,@email,@price,@description)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@path", (object)txtUpload.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", (object)FileData));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", (object)txtSellUsername.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", (object)txtSellEmail.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", (object)txtSellPrice.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@description", (object)txtSellDescription.Text));


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

and Downloaded like this

```
FileStream FS = null;
        byte[] dbbyte;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCFTest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM upload where Id='" + txtBuyId.Text + "'", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dbbyte = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];

            string filepath = (rootDirectory + "\\Profiles\\" + txtBuyPrice.Text.ToString() + ".txt" );
            FS = new FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            FS.Write(dbbyte, 0, dbbyte.Length);
            FS.Close();
            con.Close();
        }*/
```

From this i have worked out how to upload via the web service like this

```
  try
        {
            byte[] FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(txtUpload.Text);
            UserDetailsService.SellProfiles sellprofiles = new UserDetailsService.SellProfiles();

            sellprofiles.Upload = txtUpload.Text;
            sellprofiles.Upload2 = FileData;
            sellprofiles.Username = txtSellUsername.Text;
            sellprofiles.Email = txtSellEmail.Text;
            sellprofiles.Price = txtSellPrice.Text;
            sellprofiles.Name = txtSellProfileName.Text;
            sellprofiles.Description = txtSellDescription.Text;
            obj.InsertSellingProfiles(sellprofiles);

            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Your profile has been successfully uploaded!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                new Menu().Show();
                this.Close();
            }
```

But now i have tried a various amount of ways to download the binary data from the web service but i am struggling to find a solution!

Can anyone help me with this? Hopefully my code can help someone more experienced to help me find a solution

Thank you

I have attempted to download from service like this:

```
  UserDetailsService.Service1Client obj1 = new UserDetailsService.Service1Client();
        byte[] dbbyte;
        FileStream FS;

        UserDetailsService.Service1Client sc = new UserDetailsService.Service1Client();
        if (sc.CheckIfProfileExists(txtBuyId.Text, txtBuyProduct.Text))
        {
            BuyProfile.Id = txtBuyId.Text;
            BuyProfile.Name = txtBuyProduct.Text;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = obj1.DownLoadProfile(txtBuyId.Text, txtBuyProduct.Text);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dbbyte = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];

                string filepath = (rootDirectory + "\\Profiles\\" + txtBuyProduct.Text.ToString() + ".txt");
                FS = new FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                FS.Write(dbbyte, 0, dbbyte.Length);
                FS.Close();
```

Comment: you can return byte[] from your webservice. Why don't you do that.

Comment: Return Byte? so on the service have the standard "select all where match id etc" Draw the information to the program.. then return "data" (byte) hmm

Comment: yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a method in your webservice like this

```
public byte[] GetFileBytes(strubg someParam)
{
   //read from database and return here
}
```

Comment: Ill give it a go and see how it goes. Ill let you know. Thanks for some help

Comment: Check the new code at the top, i tried this but this did not work

Comment: getting any exception? by the way why are you returning datatable? you can return directly byte[] as i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: was trying to store the byte file into a dt, then download from the dt.  Sorry, but i am a newbie programming, been programming less than a year. Im confused completely

Comment: try returning a byte[] directly from your method.